# Why in my post is only one item? CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp

I have table in my view. This table is in form. I need send all items from table to my controller. I create form but he is sending only one item, last item...
Here is my table in View:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Goodsandoffer');?>
    <table id="GoodSandOffersTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead><tr>

            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id','ID'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('nazwa','Nazwa'); ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('kodKreskowy','Kod EAN'); ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('cenaSprzedazyBrutto','Cena sprzedaży brutto'); ?></th>                       
                        <th>Cena Promocyjna</th>
                        <th>Akcja</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
        <tbody>
       <?php $x =0;?>
        <?php foreach ($goods as $good): ?>
        <tr>


            <td><?php echo h($goodID= $good['Good']['id']);?></td>
            <td><?php echo h($good['Good']['nazwa']);?></td>
            <td><?php echo h($good['Good']['kodKreskowy']);?></td>
            <td><?php echo h($good['Good']['cenaSprzedazyBrutto']);?></td>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('promotionaloffer_id',array("default"=>$prom['Promotionaloffer']['id'],'type'=>'hidden'));?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('good_id',array("default"=>$good['Good']['id'],'type'=>'hidden'));?>
            <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('cenaPromocyjna', array('id' => 'cenaPromocyjna'.$x));?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php $x = $x + 1 ;?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>


        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Dodaj')); ?>
```

Here is controller:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                        debug($this->request->data);
}
```

And when Im debug I got this:

```
\app\Controller\GoodsandoffersController.php (line 110)
array(
    'Goodsandoffer' => array(
        'promotionaloffer_id' => '3',
        'good_id' => '20',
        'cenaPromocyjna' => '3'
    )
)
```

In array I have only last item from table. I need all. What Im doing wrong?

Comment: Did you take a look at the HTML that's generated? Your field names seem to all have the same name by the looks of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with CakePHP myself but it looks like all your fields in your table rows have the same name (promotionaloffer_id, good_id, cenaPromocyjna):

```
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('promotionaloffer_id',array("default"=>$prom['Promotionaloffer']['id'],'type'=>'hidden'));?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('good_id',array("default"=>$good['Good']['id'],'type'=>'hidden'));?>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('cenaPromocyjna', array('id' => 'cenaPromocyjna'.$x));?></td>
```

In order to receive all values, you need to indicate them with array keys like so:

```
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('promotionaloffer_id['.$good['Good']['id'].']',array("default"=>$prom['Promotionaloffer']['id'],'type'=>'hidden'));?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('good_id['.$good['Good']['id'].']',array("default"=>$good['Good']['id'],'type'=>'hidden'));?>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('cenaPromocyjna['.$good['Good']['id'].']', array('id' => 'cenaPromocyjna'.$x));?></td>
```

This would result in input names like

- promotionaloffer_id[0], good_id[0], cenaPromocyjna[0]
- promotionaloffer_id[1], good_id[1], cenaPromocyjna[1]
- ...
- promotionaloffer_id[x], good_id[x], cenaPromocyjna[x]

Where x is the good-id.